# What is the specific function of a triac inside a soldering station?

Tags: triac

I'm trying to understand the different parts inside a soldering station. One of the components i found was a Triac.

I've tried to find an explanation for the use of a Triac inside the soldering station. Can someone explain me this?

Comment: it's probably for chopping the waveform, for power control.

Comment: It's used to turn on and off the heating element and it's a part of thermo regulation loop.

Comment: I see two answers here posted as comments.

Answer (score 4):

A triac can be used to switch AC power on and off to the heater in the soldering iron, or it can be used to phase control the power to get smoother control.

Triacs are only useful for switching low frequency (such as mains frequency) AC power. Once switched on they stay on until the current through them drops to near zero (tens of mA typically). So they can only switch at a maximum of double the mains frequency.

In a good soldering station you will have a temperature sensor and closed-loop control of the soldering tip temperature. In a less good one you may have open loop control of the power to the heater, like a light dimmer.

Comment: why do you want to switch the power on and off? Is this to get a higher efficiency?

Comment: It's to regulate the temperature of the tip.

Comment: Switching on/off rather than phase control creates less EMI compared to phase control and can be adequately fast. Controlling tip power with a linear amplifier would be very wasteful of energy and relatively expensive.